# Can I send transactions from tz1 to KT1 and viceversa?

Tags: transactions, address

Can I send `kind: "transaction"` operations from a tz1 address to a KT1 address and vice versa? Can any weird behavior occur or is some special operation needed?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can send transactions from TZ1 to KT1 addresses and back